# Allow only numbers/year between rounded brackets

Tags: regex, brackets

For a website I want to allow only the year of production between rounded brackets with a RegEx.

**Allowed:**

```
Movie 1 (2010)
```

**Disallowed:**

```
Movie 2 (2010 English)

Movie 2 (01-01-2010)
```

What I want is a RegEx that will detect when letters are between the brackets or a combination of letters, spaces and numbers.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
/^.+\(\d{4}\)$/
```

Comment: That will match "Movie 1 (Foo) Bar (2004)" too.

Comment: @A.H. I think it works properly because the `$` matches the end of the string and `.+` is greedy matching.

Comment: Exactly my point: Te `^.+` part will match "Movie 1 (Foo) Bar. Greedy is of no concern here, because greedy will only make a difference, if there are multiple ways to match an input - greedy will never make a match fail. Simple try it.

Comment: It wasn't specified in the question as to whether "a (b) c (0000)" is allowed or disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do just fine:

```
/\(.*?([0-9]{4}).*?\)/
```

You can then use `$1` to retrieve the year.